# What have I done wrong? in Newton's method calculation?

Tags: newton-raphson

So I am using Newton's method. And for equation $f(x)=\sin(x)/(3+\sin(x))$ I differentiated it and I got $3\cos(x)/(3+\sin(x))^2$ which is checked by wolfram alpha. However, when I apply Newton's method on my own my results do not match my expected result calculated by a Newton's method software which is shown below [image]

The picture is what I am aiming, but it seems like there are some errors.

. What is the error? I really could not find it.

Justin Chan St georges school IB mathematics EE

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not show us your work it is difficult to find the error. It must be either in the function that you must iterate, which should be
$$
N(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=x-\frac13\,(3+\sin x)\tan x,
$$
or in the computations with that function. The  results given by the software are correct.